# Unable to join two nodes in Compositor

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I used everything to solve the issue, deleting the nodes, installing 8.2 version, Shift+CRL+left click but no avail!
I attached a picture of the problem below
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct0Hp.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you add a **screenshot** of your whole interface ?

Comment: Yes. Please wait a sec

Comment: @Gorgious i have uploaded the screenshoot. See above

Comment: @RayMairlot can you help me with this one?

Comment: Enable the Node Wrangler addon.

Comment: @susu already on

Comment: @susu how would that fix it? Do you know what the node wrangler add on even does?

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to plug a composite node into the denoise node- or any other node for that matter.

The composite node represents the **output** the compositor will return. What you plug into it will be returned as the output.

To use the denoise node, you will instead need to hook it up to the **render layers** node. This is the output from the render result you have just generated. Plug "Noisy Image" into "Image", "Normal" into "Denoising Normal", and "Denoising Albedo" into "Albedo". Now drag the output "Image" of the denoise node into the input "image" of the composite node.

The compositor is designed to change the render result, sort of like an image editor except it is node based and more powerful.

Comment: But I'm unable to connect anything. I'm following a Blender Guru Tutorial, it surely connects for him but I'm unable to click and drag to link any node.